# textview position by background imageview

Tags: android, layout, textview, imageview

I have background imageview (green with 3 red circle) and 3 textview (A,B,C).
how can I put textviews exactly on center of red circles that support multi screen devices , portrait/landscape?

[image]

**Edited**:
maybe I asked wrong question.

my main question is:

1- I've an image in my layout for example like this:

[image]

2- I want put textview on image in exact positions

[image]

when I test on different screen size , position of textviews changed.

[image]

Comment: see the Answer Below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00FF00"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_txt"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="A"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_txt2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="B"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_txt3"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="C"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Save in drawable **bg_red.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:shape="oval">
        <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
        <stroke android:color="#FF0000" android:width="5dip"/>
        <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
    </shape>
```

The **Output** is :

[image]

Comment: thanks , but my question is : how can i put textview in position that matched with background and dont change by screen size

Answer (score 0):

**In the text view xml attribute**

```
android:gravity="center"
```

and make the circle xml file width as warp content

```
width = "wrap_content"
```